# Solidity transaction error: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

I'm trying to send some Ether between contracts but I'm getting this error:

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

My contract:

```
contract test {
    address public owner;
    address payable public receiverContract;

    constructor(address payable _receiverContract) payable{
       receiverContract = _receiverContract;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendEther() public payable {
        receiverContract.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    receive() external payable {
  }
}
```

The receiver contract also has a `receive() external payable` function and I'm getting the error when calling `sendEther()` with some Ethers and after seeding the test contract with some Ethers

Answer (score 0):

The message indicate that you should add a requirement to test if the user actually have the Ether he is trying to send to the contract.

````
    address public owner;
    address payable public receiverContract;

    constructor(address payable _receiverContract) payable{
       receiverContract = _receiverContract;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendEther() public payable {
        require(address(this).balance > msg.value, "Not enough funds" );
        receiverContract.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    receive() external payable {
  }
} ```
````